# Youtube thumbnail is not visible due to security alert in google play console

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube-data-api, google-play-console, android-security

I have integrated Youtube Data Api v3 in 3 apps. Everything was working fine. Few days back got the following security alert in google play console -

**Security alert**

**Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys. Please see this Google Help Center article for details.**

**Vulnerable locations:**

**com.****.*****.activities.YoutubePlayerActivity->onActivityResult
com.****.*****.activities.YoutubePlayerActivity->onCreate**

**Affects APK version 25,9.**

What possibly wrong was maybe I didn't change the youtube api key in all apps. I just created for one of the app and used it in other apps.
So I created different api keys in google cloud console for all apps with adding security of SHA1 & package name then installed the apps with new respective keys.But still I am not able to see the thumbnail of Youtube video even though the thumbnail url is working on the browser & the problem is still showing in google play console.

thumbnailurlsample : http://img.youtube.com/vi/qigAsdGouX4/0.jpg

Comment: Have you check this [info about exposed GCP API keys](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9287711)? - being honest with you, I'm not an Android Developer, but, the way I understand the error is that Google advices not no stored your API keys in code, so, you need to follow their guidelines (*exposed in the previous link*). Is nothing related with the thumbnail or any logic in your app's source code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe other member of Stack Overflow with more knowledge than me can help you, but you need to explain or (*even better*) add the code you're using for handle or store your API keys - do NOT expose your real API keys in your question.
Good luck.

Comment: @Mauricio Arias Olave I don't think there is any issue with the code it's something related to api keys on google cloud console